# Magento order address update API

Tags: php, api, soap, magento-1.9

Is there any way to edit order address via API (preferably SOAP v2) in Magento (v 1.9.1.0)?

I've found method [customerAddressUpdate](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customerAddress/customer_address.update.html), but it only updates customer address, not order address.